# Copy a txt file with today date as file name (YYMMDD)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Everyday I create a data log with today's date (eg. `ERR150921.txt`). I need to copy this file to the server like a backup.

This is my current code:

```
SET ServerPath=\\IYA-PC\Shared
SET ClientPath=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Data Log

echo.
echo Copying Files to Server...
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "%ClientPath%\*.txt" /B /O:F') DO SET NewestFile=%%I
xcopy "%ClientPath%" "%ServerPath%\%NewestFile%" /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
```

I got it from a post here. It copies the recently updated files.
The problem is that I do not need all the updated files. I just need to copy the file created today.

Comment: You should link the post you got the code from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample will copy every files that have today date as name before extension. ie it will copy any of this;

```
"ERR150921.txt"
"21184150921.txt"
"2526150921.txt"
"29056-150921.txt
"150921.txt"
"ABCDEF-150921.txt"
```

.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "_timestamp=%YY%%MM%%DD%"

SET "ServerPath=\\IYA-PC\Shared"
SET "ClientPath=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Data Log"

echo.
echo Copying Files to Server...
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "%ClientPath%\*.txt" /B') DO (
    set "filename=%%~nI"
    if "!filename:~-6!"=="%_timestamp%" (
        echo xcopy "%%~I" "%ServerPath%\%%~nxI" /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
    )
)
```

Comment: @iyaSheep: `dir` has no `/OF` (see `dir /?`). Do you mean `/OD`?

Comment: I just want to copy the file. Sorry. I changed xcopy "%%~I" "%ServerPath%\%%~nxI" /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y to xcopy "%ClientPath%\%%I" "%ServerPath%" /y to make it work. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @aschipfl You mean `dir /A-D`? :) Because /O is for sorting

Answer (score 0):

Get today's date, and transform it to your file name

```
SET ServerPath=\\IYA-PC\Shared
SET ClientPath=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Data Log

echo.
echo Copying Files to Server...

SET FILE_NAME=ERR%date:~2,2%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%.txt

FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "%ClientPath%\%FILE_NAME%" /B /O:F') DO SET NewestFile=%%I
xcopy "%ClientPath%" "%ServerPath%\%NewestFile%" /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
```